# Attaching condition to find() in controller

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

i've been trying to learn more about how to have fat models and skinny controllers the right way, because before my models would have basically no code and i'm trying to change that. My function works, but now i'm trying to combine two find() queries that look almost exactly the same except one of them has a simple condition.

My model looks something like this:

```
function pieChart() {
    //Get Data for PieChart
    $this->RecordDrug->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';
    $records = array();
    $records=$this->RecordDrug->find('list',
        array('fields' => array( 'Drug.drug', 'sum'),
            'contain' => array( 'Drug', 'Record' ),
            'group'  => 'Drug.Drug'
            ));
    $this->set('output',$records); 
    return $records;
}

I will have two controllers using this. One of them will use this code as is, just simply call the pieChart() function. The other controller will have to see a condition that only selects the users entries. So 

'conditions' => array('Record.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
```

How do I go about this the right way? I think i'm having trouble with this because my OOP knowledge is pretty limited. If anyone has any examples or resources that can help me make my find() functions more efficient and streamlined, i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done that kind of things very simple:

```
public function myQuery($conditions = null) {

    $this->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';

    $result = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions,
                                       'fields' => array('Drug.drug', 'sum'),
                                       'contain' => array('Drug','Record'),
                                       'group'  => 'Drug.Drug'
    ));

   return $result;
}
```

Now you can call this with your argument:

```
$conditions = array('Record.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'));
$data = $this->RecordDrug->myQuery($conditions);
```

Or without it:

```
$data = $this->RecordDrug->myQuery();
```

Note that in this case you need to put `myQuery()` in to RecordDrug model and you need to use `'all'` instead  of `'list'`, because `'list'` doesn't support `contain` option.

So now if you have additional conditions - you just need to pass it in the argument. If you leave it null - it do the query without the conditions statement.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot for this that cleared up a lot of things for me